# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '/' while compiling ejs but works if I remove <% include ./src/myTemplate.ejs%>

Tags: javascript, ejs

This is my code and I dont really know how to use EJS. It'd great to get help.

```
    <% include ./partials/header.ejs %>
        <h1> Welcome to index page</h1>
        <% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
            <div>
                <h2>
                <%= blog.title %>
                </h2>
                <img src="<%= blog.image %>">
                <br>
                <span style="font-size: 15px;">
                    <%= blog.created %>
                </span>
                <p>
                    <%= blog.body.substring(0,100) %>
                </p>
                <a  href="/blogs/<%=blog._id%>">Read More </a>
            </div>
        <% }); %>
        <% include ./partials/footer.ejs %>
```

But everything works if I remove  <% include ./src/myTemplate.ejs%>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be using syntax for an older version. There was recently an update that changed the way `include` works. Try this instead:

```
<%- include('partials/header.ejs') %>
```

and

```
<%- include('partials/footer.ejs') %>
```